# exFAT slow on MacBook - how to improve performance?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk, exfat

When I copy data from my MacBook Pro (M1) to my external drive *(HDD USB 3.0 - exFAT)* it is slow *(60 MByte/sec)*.

When I copy the same data from a Windows PC on that drive, I reached a much better performance *(120MByte/sec)*. Is there a way to improve the exFAT performance on Mac? I disabled Spotlight search on external drives, but this does nothing. I have a second external drive, formated in MacOsExtended with no performance issues. But for the other drive I need exFat to transfer Backup data.

Comment: Open system preferences and check how it’s connected on the USB level (what speed)? Compare to windows (not sure how to do that in Windows.) if it truely is the due to the file system then there isn’t likely anything to be done. It’s a kernel driver handling exFAT in macOS.

Comment: I checked it in the systeminformation:
USB 3.1 Bus:
Drive for Host-Controller:AppleT6000USBXHCI
Speed: Up to 5GBit/s

But is that normal, has nobody the same problems?

Comment: I’ve never experienced the same problem, but I’ve also (never written more than a minute or so at a time to a *fat disk.

Comment: I'm slightly worried you're using ExFAT for 'backup data'. ExFAT is a poor choice for that; it cannot store unix permissions/ACLs & will break Apple containers such as Photos libraries & Logic saves.